# How to deserialize a JSON object containing two arrays

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm using VB.Net, MVC 5.  I'm creating a javaScript object then passing that object to my controller using ajax and JSON.

My object is created like this:

```
var myEdits = {
                    arrayOfIDs: [],
                    arrayOfValues : []
                };
```

This is how I send the object to the server:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/ViewDetails/EditConfirmation',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'myEdits': myEdits }
            })
                .success(function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                })
                .error (function (status) {
                    alert(status);
                })
```

My string when it hits the server looks like this:

> "{"arrayOfIDs":["53","54","55","56"],"arrayOfValues":["foo","bar","narf","woohoo"]}"

I've tried creating a class like this:

```
    Function CompareEdits(myEdits As Object) As IEnumerable(Of compareEdits)
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

        Dim model As compareEdits
        model = serializer.Deserialize(Of compareEdits)(myEdits)

        Return model
    End Function

End Class

Public Class compareEdits
    Public Property arrayOfIDs As List(Of String)
    Public Property arrayOfValues As List(Of String)
End Class
```

I've also tried deserializing it like this:

```
    Function CompareEdits(myEdits As Object) As IEnumerable(Of compareEdits)
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

        Dim model
        model = serializer.Deserialize(Of Array)(myEdits)

        Return model
    End Function
```

I keep getting this error when I try to deserialize my JSON string:

> {"Conversion from type 'String()' to type 'String' is not valid."}

The first array in the string is used to decide which field to update, the second array in the string is the actual value.

How do I properly deserialize this string?

Comment: The first one using teh `compareEdits` Type works fine for me, try not casting the jString to `Object`.  Pass it as `(myEdits As String`) the serialized output is string.  Sine you do have 2 arrays inside a class, the return type (`IEnumerable`) seems wrong.

Comment: @plutonix you are absolutely correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is mostly correct:

```
' the serialized data is string, dont box it
' the return is a Type containing the Lists/Arrays
Function CompareEdits(myEdits As String) As compareEdits
    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()

    Dim model = serializer.Deserialize(Of compareEdits)(myEdits)

    Return model
End Function
```

The return Type is definitely wrong: you are deserializing to a Type which contains the 2 arrays/lists, so `As IEnumerable` isnt right.

I'm not sure why you get the error or where, I accidentally typed it in without those 2 aspects and it worked fine.  The error mentioned likely to result from the second method.